# In xml file, append an attribute to node element if that attribute not exist using shell script

Tags: shell, unix, xmllint

I have the below requirement on xml file using Shell script

Standalone.xml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:11.0">
 <profile>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:2.0">
            <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-enabled="false" scan-interval="5000" deployment-timeout="600"/>
        </subsystem>
        ...........Other subsystems tags.......
<server>
```

Would like to check node   contains the attribute "deployment-timeout" or not

```
if exist read the value then check 
         if the value is <900 
            update the value to 900
         else
            Leave as it is 
else 
    Append attribute with value i.e deployment-timeout="900" to node <deployment-scanner> at the end like this
*<deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-enabled="false" scan-interval="5000" deployment-timeout="900"/>*

Please help me...

advance thanks
```

Comment: Use a specialised tool such as xmlstarlet.

Comment: Again I need to install this xmlstarlet in the unix environment which is not possible at the moment.... Is there any other way using tools xmllint xmlpath,xpath,xsltproc,XMLfiles? if you have plz post full code (coz I am not good at using these XML tools).